# Invalid thread access exception

Tags: java, multithreading, swt

I'm working on an Eclipse RAP application. A SWT Invalid Thread Access Exception is thrown everytime when two or more users perform UI read/write operations on application simultaneously.A different session is maintained for each user.

I've tried using Display.asyncExec() Display.syncExec() and even tried putting the code (Read/write operations) in synchronized block. But nothing seems to work.
However the application works fine when only one user is using it.

Exceptions are thrown by reading or writing data from SWT Controls inside the listener of another control.

Here is  sample code which is called when btnSave is clicked :

```
   btnSave.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {
    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {

       cmbBox.getText();// invalid thread access
       //OR
       cmbBox.setText();// invalid thread access    

    }
});
// btnSave is a Button 
// cmbBox  is a ComboBox
```

Can someone help me solve this issue ? Thanks

Comment: What is `ComboBox` and where is it defined?

Comment: What is an 'SWT Web Application'? How is this code being accessed?

Comment: Are you maybe talking about [Eclipse RAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_AJAX_Platform)?

Comment: If so, there is a [tread in the Eclipse forum](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/369562/) that sounds awfully similar to your problem.

Comment: I declared cmbBox as `static` which was causing this error. Now the problem is solved. Thanks guys